# Help with constructing homeomorphism for this identification

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Consider the following triangles:

[image]

I have shown that $T$ is homeomorphic to as disc. Here is the proof:

First note that one can prove the following theorem:

The mapping $f^\ast : X/\sim_f \to Y$ induces by a continuous surjective map $f: X \to Y$ where $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff is a homeomorphism.

Now consider $T$ as a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ such that $A$ coincides with the origin and one of its edges $AD$ coincides with the $x$-axis and the other with the $y$-axis. Assume points in $\mathbb R^2$ are given in polar coordinates $(r, \varphi)$. Define a map $f: T \to D^2 \subset \mathbb R^2$ where $D^2$ lies centered at the origin as $(r, \varphi) \mapsto (r, 4 \varphi )$. Then $f$ is continuous and surjective. Note that $T$ is compact and $D^2$ is Hausdorff. It follows that $f$ induces a homeomorphism $f^\ast : T / \sim_f \to D^2$.

Now I want to show that the second triangle is homeomorphic to a Moebius strip  but I can't seem to apply the same argument as I'm not sure how to choose suitable coordinates for a Moebius strip. How to define the coordinates? I suppose it would have to be in $\mathbb R^3$. Or is there a better argument than the one I use for $T$?

Answer (score 2):

Big hint: make a cut from the vertex $A$ in the top left, to the point between $E$ and $F$ on the opposite edge. Now, identify the left and top edge of the triangle, keeping in mind the orientation of the cut that you've made. You should see a similarity between this representation of the space, and the usual representation of the Möbius strip as a square with two edges identified with with opposing orientations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could work (I was really hoping to apply the theorem but that didn't work even after a lot of thinking):

The following deformation is a homeomorphism: pulling $C$ and $B$ (the neighbours of $A$) up until $S$ is a [trapezoid](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b5/Isosceles_trapezoid.svg). Then stretching the shorter parallel side until $S$ becomes a square. But this space is the Möbius strip. Hence $S$ is homeomorphic to the Möbius strip.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you will still have three representative points for the point $A$ in this quotient space diagram and so it is not the usual representation of the Mobius strip. You will need to do some cutting in order to get the usual 'square with opposite sides identified with opposing orientation' representation, as in my answer below. Is there something about my answer which wasn't clear enough?

Comment: @DanielRust Thanks. Well I wanted to apply the theorem I mention in the question. I still don't really understand how to prove it rigorously.